# Best way to spread load on monitor clamp

Tags: forces

Let me know if this belongs in DIY; I'm posting it here first because I want to learn about the various forces involved so it doesn't happen to me.

I saw this monitor clamp crush a hollow Ikea desk:
[image]

To prevent this, the load of the clamp should be spread. But spread how? Say I had a 1.5mm thick sheet of steel.

1. If I placed it here, would the same thing have happened, but this time the crack would have run along the long side of the steel sheet? Does the fact the width of the steel doesn't go past the front of the clamp make a difference?

[image]

2. If I moved it forward slightly, I predict it would have prevented damage to the desk. But why? Isn't the load spread amongst the same amount of surface area?

[image]

3. Would it make a difference if the steel sheet was placed like this? I think the steel sheet would have a sort of lever effect as the centre of gravity is closer to the steel sheet load spreader

[image]

4. Does the tightness of the clamp affect anything? eg loose clamp, exaggerated for effect, the two red dots are where the force is concentrated:

[image]

tight clamp, the red lines are where the force is spread:

[image]

Or would there still be a concentration of force at the red dots as the monitor moves the centre of gravity and adds a rotational effect?

Comment: Some lightweight Ikea desk tops have literally cardboard inside, keeping the veneer surfaces apart. They are simply not designed for clamping things to the desk top. There have been reports of people making a hole in the desk top by leaning their elbows on it! Get a desk with a solid MDF top and you won't need to mess about with steel plates etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a loose answer to help you avoid crushing your desk. I do not get into torques and so forth that might help you calculate.

The pictures for question 4) are relevant. The weight of the monitor puts a large force on the front of the clamp. If you tighten the clamp, it squeezes the top and bottom of the desk, increasing the force. The force is concentrated at the edge of the clamp.

A still piece of steel would help a lot. You might have the same force on the steel, but the steel would spread it out. No small area of the desk would get a concentrated force.

You seem to have the right idea for 1) and 2). For 3), no the leverage would not get large.

Comment: So I assume there is no difference when placing the metal at 1 vs 2?

Comment: I would put it so there is no chance of the front edge digging into the desk.